# Is it possible to add a QTableWidget inside another QTableWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I have a `QTableWidget` where I would like to populate on the fields with another `QTableWidget`.

This is something it would look like:

```
--------------------------
Name | Class | Section    |
---------------------------
     |       | Some Text  |
 A   |  1    | CheckBox 1 |
     |       | CheckBox 2 |
---------------------------
```

I want to add a `Table B` in each of the fields in the section column so that it is easier for me to deal with each checkboxes for each item in `Table A` (main `Table`).

Is it possible? Are there any better ways to approach this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use custom widget instead:

```
QWidget *wgt = new QWidget();
QVBoxLayout *hlayout = new QVBoxLayout;
QCheckBox *check1 = new QCheckBox("1");
QCheckBox *check2 = new QCheckBox("2");
QLineEdit *lineEdit = new QLineEdit;
lineEdit->setText("test");
hlayout->addWidget(lineEdit);
hlayout->addWidget(check1);
hlayout->addWidget(check2);
wgt->setLayout(hlayout);
ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(0,2,wgt);
ui->tableWidget->resizeRowsToContents();
```

With `setCellWidget` you can also add another `QTableWidget` but I think that `QWidget` will be enough.

You can add for example: `lineEdit->setStyleSheet("border:0px");` and your lineEdit will be without borders or use just `QLabel` instead, it is widget, do all what you need.

Result:

[image]